# Automation Error Catastrophic Failure

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-powerpoint

I am trying to use excel VBA to copy some charts to Powerpoint slides using the below codes, but it shows error "Automation Error Catastrophic Failure". I can not figure out what is the problem. I am wondering if the excel file size is too big. how i can fix the problem?

```
Sub ExcelToPres()
Dim PPT As Object
Set PPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
PPT.Visible = True
PPT.Presentations.Open Filename:="C:\test\test.pptx"
copy_chart "Sheet1", 2  ' Name of the sheet to copy graph and slide number the graph is to be pasted in
PPT.Save
PPT.Close
End Sub


Public Function copy_chart(sheet, slide)


Dim PPApp As Object
Dim PPPres As Object
Dim PPSlide As Object

Set PPApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")


Set PPApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
Set PPPres = PPApp.ActivePresentation
'PPApp.ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewSlide
PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (slide)

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 13").Chart.CopyPicture _ ****
Appearance:=xlScreen, Size:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture 


'PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide PPSlide.SlideIndex

Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex)
With PPSlide
' paste and select the chart picture
.Shapes.Paste.Select
' align the chart
PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True
PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignMiddles, True
End With

' Clean up
Set PPSlide = Nothing
Set PPPres = Nothing
Set PPApp = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error? Did you try a smaller Excel file (to determine if your suspicion is right or wrong)?

Answer (score 0):

One or the other of your routines should invoke PPT and get a PPT object to work with, not both.

One thing I'd be immediately suspicious of is that the cleanup routine in copy_chart is closing the PPT app object, so when control returns to the calling subroutine, the object is null.  If the error occurs on the "PPT.Save" line, I'll put money on it.  ;-)

In any case, there's other stuff in the code you've posted that's bad practice.  Never select anything in PPT unless you need to, for example.  Use object references instead.  I've made a whole bunch of mods to your example code but haven't tested it here; take it for what it's worth, but give it a try.

```
Sub ExcelToPres()
Dim PPT As Object
Dim PPTPres as Object
Set PPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
PPT.Visible = True
Set PPTPres = PPT.Presentations.Open Filename:="C:\test\test.pptx"
copy_chart "Sheet1", 2, PPTPres  ' Name of the sheet to copy graph and slide number the graph is to be pasted in
PPTPres.Save
PPTPres.Close
' optionally
PPT.Quit

End Sub


Public Function copy_chart(sheet as String, lSlide as Long, PPTPres as Object)

Dim PPSlide As Object
Dim PPShapeRange as Object

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 13").Chart.CopyPicture _ ****
Appearance:=xlScreen, Size:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture 

Set PPSlide = PPTPres.Slides(lSlide)

With PPSlide
' paste and select the chart picture
set PPShapeRange = .Shapes.Paste

' align the chart
With PPShapeRange
.Align msoAlignCenters, True
.Align msoAlignMiddles, True
End With


End Function
```